# 'Meteor code must always run within a Fiber' error when using NPM package

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, meteorite, node-fibers

I'm using `Meteor.require('npmPackage')` to use a NPM package. However I seem to be getting an error when writing to mongo in npm package's callback function.

**Error:**

`Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.`

**Code**

```
npmPackage.getInfo(function(err, data) {
    UserSession.insert({
        key: 'info',
        value: data
    });
    console.log(data);
});
```

I tried wrapping the code within Fiber but the same error message is still shown:

```
Fiber(function() {

    npmPackage.getInfo(function(err, data) {
        UserSession.insert({
            key: 'info',
            value: data
        });
        console.log(data);
    });

}).run();
```

**Question:** How should `Meteor.bindEnvironment` be used to get this to work?

Comment: It would be wise to place the version of the Meteor you are using. Meteor is in constant development, and a newer version could break code developed in older versions. Also, much of the API is also undocumented. What developers do is study the shipped packages.

Comment: Will do that in the future. I'm currently using v0.6.6.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `wrapAsync` e.g

```
npmPackage.getInfoSync = Meteor._wrapAsync(npmPackage.getInfo.bind(npmPackage));

var data = npmPackage.getInfoSync();

UserSession.insert({
    key: 'info',
    value: data
});
```

You can add params into `npmPackage.getInfoSync()` if you want (if it takes any).

The thing is the callback needs to be in a fiber which is where the error comes from. The best way to do it is with `Meteor.bindEnvironment`. `Meteor._wrapAsync` does this for you and makes the code synchronous. Which is even better :)

Meteor._wrapAsync is an undocumented method that takes in a method who's last param is a callback with the first param as `error` and the second as a `result`. Just like your callback.

It then wraps the callback into a `Meteor.bindEnvironment` and waits for it then returns the value synchronously.

Comment: Thanks it works! How do I also retrieve `err` from `npmPackage.getInfoSync()` and do the error checking like in the original non-working code?