# How to get an async data in a function with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm a newbie with Meteor and I'm trying to get an async data from the Heroku API.

**Server side code:**

```
heroku = Meteor.require("heroku");

Meteor.methods({
    'getHeroku': function getHeroku(app){
        client = new heroku.Heroku({key: "xxxxxx"});
        client.get_app(app, function (error, result) {
            return result;
        });
    }
});
```

**Client side code:**

```
Template.herokuDashboard.helpers({
    appInfo: function() {
        Meteor.call('getHeroku', "meathook-api", function (error, result) {
            console.warn(result);
        } );
    }
});
```

Heroku takes a while to answer so the answer is `undefined`.

So what is the best way to catch the async result?

Thank you.

Comment: See [this meteorpedia entry](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Category:Fibers_and_Async) on fibers and async.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041177/meteor-code-must-always-run-within-a-fiber-error-when-using-npm-package/20043342#20043342

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### General solution :

#### Client Side:

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
        Template.herokuDashboard.helpers({
            appInfo: function() {
                return Session.get("herokuDashboard_appInfo");
            }
        });
        Template.herokuDashboard.created = function(){
            Meteor.call('getData', function (error, result) {
                Session.set("herokuDashboard_appInfo",result);
            } );
        }
    }
```

There is no way to **directly** return results from Meteor.call.
However there are at least 2 solutions (@akshat and @Hubert OG):
[How to use Meteor methods inside of a template helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147813/how-to-use-meteor-methods-inside-of-a-template-helper)

### Server Side (Meteor._wrapAsync):

Using Meteor._wrapAsync :

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  var asyncFunc = function(callback){
      setTimeout(function(){
          // callback(error, result);
          // success :
          callback(null,"result");
          // failure:
          // callback(new Error("error"));
      },2000)
  }
  var syncFunc = Meteor._wrapAsync(asyncFunc);
  Meteor.methods({
      'getData': function(){
          var result;
          try{
               result = syncFunc();
          }catch(e){
              console.log("getData method returned error : " + e);
          }finally{
              return result;
          }

      }
  });
}
```

**Proper** usage of Future library:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

    Meteor.methods({
        'getData': function() {
            var fut = new Future();
            setTimeout(
                Meteor.bindEnvironment(
                    function() {
                        fut.return("test");
                    },
                    function(exception) {
                        console.log("Exception : ", exception);
                        fut.throw(new Error("Async function throw exception"));
                    }
                ),
                1000
            )
            return fut.wait();
        }
    });
}
```

Using Future library **WITHOUT Meteor.bindEnvironment** is **NOT RECOMMENDED**, see:

- https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-what-is-meteor-bindenvironment
- @imslavko comment from 18.07.2014
- @Akshat answer : [What's going on with Meteor and Fibers/bindEnvironment()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994951/whats-going-on-with-meteor-and-fibers-bindenvironment)

There is also 3rd approach using [Async utilities](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-npm/)

Comment: Thank you Kuba, but I have already tried that. Maybe I'm doing wrong because it gives me this error: http://cl.ly/image/0A2M2x143k0C

Full server side code: http://pastebin.com/RKQH0tzF

Comment: I changed `fut.ret` to `fut.return`. That should work.

Comment: Same error :( `TypeError: Object #<Future> has no method 'return'` and `TypeError: Object #<Future> has no method 'wait'` I think it's because it is deprecated (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1311#issuecomment-22686373) but I can't find alternative

Comment: Do this : `fut["return"](results)`

Comment: try: `return fut["wait"]()`

Comment: Same :( Trace: http://pastebin.com/n5HZAVFG // Updated final code http://pastebin.com/iQnfMwue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57289/discussion-between-kuba-wyrobek-and-skozz).

Comment: I think this answer is not accurate, here is a better one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041177/meteor-code-must-always-run-within-a-fiber-error-when-using-npm-package/20043342#20043342

Comment: @KubaWyrobek ideally you should not use Fibers directly at all. Because there is an additional dynamic environment attached on Fibers and you would not copy it over if you manually create a new fiber. Meteor.bindEnvironment both creates a fiber and attaches the correct environment for you. If you don't do this, you risk to have bugs like not having the request info or login info in a Meteor.call